# Notification queue implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, task

I have a web application and for each user(assume I'll have around 5 thousands of users) I need to provide a notification in an hour after he requests it(this is a simplified desc. ofc).

I have on mind following solutions for this:

1. Have Dictionary of `<userId, Timer>` (I suppose `Threading.Timer`, maybe other?) and handle their events.
2. Have Dictionary of `<userId, Task>` and set Continuation on each Task to my handler.
3. Have PriorityQueue of times when when notification should be raised and in a single thread process them(processing can be asynchronous or serialized) all the time. When Queue is empty, processing stops, when an item is added, processing resumes(this will require some synchronization, but not rather complex)

Which approach might be more scalable or better in terms of performance? Other approaches are also appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do anything in memory (e.g. Dictionary or Timer) since it won't survive the web server restarting (e.g. a deployment).

Comment: Application recycling will be disabled. Notifications reset on deployment is ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use Quartz or Hangfire instead. They can raise events at a specified time or according to the schedule. Thing is that they will survive server shutdown/restart. If you have a Dictionary of `<user, Timer>` in memory - it will work fine, no doubt. But, when the server goes down, so does your dictionary with all the timers and events attached to it. You have to store it (your schedule) somewhere. This is the way those packages work. The schedule is stored in a storage (MS SQL database for instance). And your scheduler is constantly overseeing this storage, firing some processes (jobs) that are due to be executed

How it will look if you choose [Quartz](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net)

[Quartz documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/index.html), pay attention to chapter 9. This kind of scheduler requires preliminary configuration

Answer (score 0):

Use option 3 and prioritise your queue by time.

After some fixed time interval you'll pick up items from the queue which should be sent to the user.

Yes, you'll need thread that will in asynchronous way fetch the items and also you need a synchronisation(lock on object) on this queue.

You might also be interested in [ConcurrentPriorityQueue](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1831994732).